# Effecient way to apply function to multiple column values in pandas perfect sum problem

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem statement wherein I want to club multiple values from a column in a dataframe and compare it against a single value from a column in another dataframe.Something similar to Perfect sum problem(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perfect-sum-problem-print-subsets-given-sum/).

I have following dataframes

`df`

| Index | Price | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 10 |
| 1 | 50 | 10 |
| 2 | 50 | 14 |
| 3 | 150 | 10 |

`df2`

| Index | Price | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 300 | 10 |

I want to find out all the Price and Rate from df whose sum is equal to Price and Rate in df2.

In the above example values from index 0,1 and 3 matches the criteria as it forms a perfect sum.

This looks like a perfect sum problem to me. How do i go about applying this perfect sum problem to the dataframe

```
def sumSubsets(sets, n, target):
 # implementation taken from below link
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perfect-sum-problem-print-subsets-given-sum/
```

Comment: You have a link to a site that explains the algorithm and shows how to do it in two programming languages. What more do you expect from an answer here?

Comment: I have to apply this algorithm to combination of columns using pandas.I am unable to figure out